# Origine di 'fare/farsene un baffo'

Tags: etymology

*Mi fa un [baffo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/baffo/)*  è un'espressione molto comune. Qual è la sua origine?

> - *Mi fa un b.* (locuz. di uso colloquiale ma di tono volg. e d’intenzione offensiva), non m’importa nulla; anche riferito a persona, per significare che non la si teme, che non s’intende tenerne conto.

Comment: Trovo curioso che le due spiegazioni proposte siano quasi opposte: in una ci si rifarebbe ai baffi per la loro importanza e come simbolo di autorità, mentre nell'altra indicherebbero una cosa di poco conto.

Comment: @DaG - personalmente trovo più plausibile la versione dei baffi come simbolo di autorità. E poi, perché i baffi sarebbero una cosa di poco conto?

Comment: Curioso che talvolta l'espressione è usata con una negazione e talvolta senza ma il significato non cambia. E.g. "...quelli del MPD non ci fanno un baffo. Anzi un baffino" - (vignetta di Giannelli 5/10/2107) "A me Maciste mi fa un baffo." - (Totò 1962)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Secondo una rubrica del [Corriere della Sera](http://forum.corriere.it/scioglilingua/21-03-2011/fare-un-baffo-e-da-capo-a-dodici-1751755.html):

I baffi, (dal greco *baphé* = tintura, forse a indicare una macchia sopra le labbra) sono, od almeno erano, simbolo apprezzato di virilità la cui forma e misura varia a seconda delle mode da una sottile striscia a imponenti e autoritari cespugli pelosi. Proprio i capricci della moda sono colpevoli di alcuni modi di dire, ormai desueti.

Ad esempio l'espressione colloquiale dal tono ironico "*fare un baffo*" col significato di infischiarsene, ostentare quindi una sicurezza davanti a una minaccia. Il detto richiama l'epoca nella quale i baffi si diffusero maggiormente.

Answer (score 0):

Quello che so io è che significa che la cosa a cui si riferisce non è importante, e nascerebbe dal fatto che *ha la stessa importanza di un paio di baffi*. è molto popolare, non conosco spiegazioni migliori